# Light sensor values differes from device to device - are the readings reliable?

Tags: motorola-moto-g, htc, sensors

I have launched an onboard sensors reading application on 2 phones: HTC M8 (Android 6) and Motorola Moto G (Android 5).

Those phones lays on my desk one just next to the other. And light sensor's readings are completely different: HTC shows `150 luxes` and Moto shows `365 luxes`.

This is a nonsense to use those sensors if readings are so different. Can those readings be treated as reliable? Can we do something about that issue?

Comment: question updated to be a question :)

Comment: You sure your program isn't wrong?

Comment: Rule of thumb: Don't trust light sensors. They are calibrated for the screen brightness, as their primary purpose is ambient brightness control. The screen brightness differs, so their calibration differs, as Android's brightness handling code probably does some standardized stuff, which has to be adjusted for the specific device screen.

Comment: This is probably because the Motorola's screen is brighter than the HTC's. But don't rely on me, as this is my 2 cents and my only source is personal experience.

Answer (score 0):

Light sensor is sensitive to angle from light source too.
Make sure that your two phones have same angle from the light source.

Comment: From the conditions the OP provided, I suspect that had already been compensated for as far as possible. Check the comments to the question.